# Angular 4 CanActivateChild doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

I'm trying to restrict access to my route system using `CanActivateChild`, however when I try to prevent user's navigation to a set of child states, the RouteGuard doesn't work, only on `CanActivate`. This is my routing module:

```
export const routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/signin", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "signin", component: SigninComponent },
    {
        path: "user",
        component: UserComponente,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: "profile", component: ProfileComponent, },
            { path: "address", component: AddressComponent, },
        ]
    },
    { path: "test", component: TestComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

In this example, if I try to access the route `test`, I can see the AuthGuard being executed, the function `canActivate` is called.

But when I try to navigate to any of the children routes (profile or address), nothing happens. Both, `canActivate` and `canActivateChild` doesn't get called on the `AuthGuard`.

This is my guard file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';
import { getString } from 'application-settings';
import { AppConfig } from './../config';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
    constructor() { }

    canActivate() {
        console.log('canActivate executing.');

        if (!getString(AppConfig.authToken)) {
            alert('You need to be logged in.');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    canActivateChild() {
        console.log('canActivateChild executing.');
        return this.canActivate();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the console, are you seeing any errors? Where is AppConfig defined? It is imported and then used here: AppConfig.authToken But it is not declared or injected in anywhere? Same for getString.

Comment: @DeborahK I just didn't put it in here. But everything is being imported and used just fine. Like I said, if I try to access the test route, I can navigate there and I do see a console.log message. Also, there is no errors. Nothing happens when I try to access address or profile routes.

Comment: Does it work if you add canActivate OR canActivateChild and not both on the same path? (They *should* work together like you have ... just wondering if using each one individually works.)

Comment: @DeborahK No. As soon as I define it in a path with children declaration, it stops working.

Comment: Can you put together a plunker that demonstrates the problem? Then we could try out the code to help us see what is wrong.

Comment: Also, I have an example of canActivate with children here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing ... though currently it is lazy loaded. It started out without lazy loading, however, and you could download the code and change it back to standard children if you want to give it a try.

Comment: @DeborahK I'm still investigating this. I tried to change just the plain text on the page and it didn't updated. After I recompiled the project manually (forcing a whole update) it started working. I'm working on a NativeScript/TypeScript project. I just don't know where the issue came from. But I think it's not related to the canActivate code itself, but one of those parts not updating the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to Inject the Router in you constructor, also you need to import it.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}
```

Because you need to let the Router know of the changes. You can return boolean, observable or UrlTree, so the router can update its state.